# asp.net page wait others server side / asynchrone page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I created an asp.net page for waiting ajax. I have one page creating something that takes 30 seconds. On every step I change a session value.

I have another page for ajax, returning the session value for showing the percentage of creation. But, I dont know why, my ajax page awaits the end of the creation of my first page. So I only get the 100% at the end.

Maybe it's because I use VS development server and not IIS server. If this is the problem, can I change settings of the development server for asynchrone execution?

Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

WebForms are not ideal for asynchronous operations.

Add SignalR to your project and use a Hub to push status data back to your page to update the current state of the process you are running Asynchronously.

An example of a technique to perform this type of asynchronous notification is covered in my blog post titled "[A Guide to using ASP.Net SignalR with RadNotifications](http://blogs.telerik.com/jefffritz/posts/13-02-01/signalr-with-radnotifications)"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ASP.Net session state to do that.  It has an implicit reader/writer lock around it, meaning your other call is probably blocking until your process finishes. You can try storing your status in a database or the cache, but it would probably be better to redesign the interaction.

Comment: I didn't know for the lock. I try to avoid database for that kind of things. I dont know how to use the cache.